# How to use ng-src when there are more conditions to check?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-class

I have 10 icons where each one for different types of alerts. I'm getting the type value from a service. I need to change the icon and style of text based on the type I'm getting from service. I'm using ng-src for changing the images.

```
    <div ng-src="{{type=='0' : 'img1.png' : (type=='1' : 'img2.png' : ())}}"></div>
    <div ng-class="{{class1: type=='1'}}">Some text</div>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the icon img source in controller. Or even set the img source like:

`$scope.iconSrc = "img" + type + ".png";`

And use in template. Same login for class.

Comment: got it, but what if my image name is different?

Comment: Then using `switch` or `if else` in controller for all type to to get related icon src.

Comment: @scary_devil then you need to define an array and use the index of it to get the filename. 
`var types = ['some.png', 'another.png']`
use it like this 
`$scope.src = types[type];`